# how to put the element of a list into a label matrix in sequence?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, matrix, tkinter, label

i am struggling with this for loop.  how to put the numbers individually in the matrix in sequence starting at position [1],[1]?  when it gets to the end of of the row, it will continue the sequence into the next row, starting at column 1.

the code that i have is either in the column form, or in the row form.

I know I am missing something, but not sure what.  thanks very much.

```
import tkinter as tk
the_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
new_list = {}

def main():

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("class basic window")
    root.geometry("800x500")
    root.config(background="LightBlue4")
    app = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()


class Application(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="ivory2", bd=2, relief=tk.RAISED)   
        self.parent = parent
        self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):

        for i in range(8):
            for j in range(6):
                self.label=tk.Label(self, relief="ridge",width=13, height=3 )
                self.label.grid(row=i, column=j, sticky="nsew", )


        i = 0
        for num in the_list:
            new_list[i,j] = tk.IntVar()
            new_list[i,j].set(num)
            self.label = tk.Label(self, textvariable=new_list[i,j])
            self.label.grid(row=i, column=j)
            i += 1




if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure if this is what you're trying to accomplish, but it sounded like you wanted to place the numbers in the_list into sequential boxes, starting at the top-left corner, working left to right, then top to bottom. If that is the case, the following code will do that.

```
import tkinter as tk

the_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
new_list = {}

def main():

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("class basic window")
    root.geometry("800x500")
    root.config(background="LightBlue4")
    app = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()

class Application(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="ivory2", bd=2, relief=tk.RAISED)   
        self.parent = parent
        self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):

        i = 0
        for r in range(8):
            for c in range(6):
                self.label=tk.Label(self, relief="ridge",width=13, height=3 )
                self.label.grid(row=r, column=c, sticky="nsew", )
                if i < len(the_list):
                    self.label['text'] = str(the_list[i])
                    i += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Hi @Ron Norris, thanks very much it worked.  i have 2 questions:  you are putting text into labels, and I understand that part.  for the theory part, why didn't you use intVar as a solution?  and what if I want to start the sequence at position [1][1], instead of [0][0]?  what code do i have to add or change? really appreciate your help.

Comment: It's really up to a developer or team policy as to which method they use to set the attribute of an object, or use a variable to do it. Both work equally well. One reason for using objects instead of variables is that the developer can change other attributes (colors, fonts, behaviors for example) if they have a handle to the object as opposed to just the variable. As to starting at a different index, you could add an offset (variable or fixed) such as [i + offset].

Comment: thanks again @Ron Norris.  I will play around with the code.

Comment: I apologize I need to ask for your help again.  I looked various examples, and came to the conclusion that the easiest way to move the sequence to position [1][1] is add "+1" to self.label.grid(row=r, column=c, sticky="nsew", ), which I did the and the sequence still start at [0][0].  the reason i need this is I already written the code for the row 0 header and column 0 header.  Do you mind assist me one last time? thanks again.

Comment: If you change the `if` statement to `if i < len(the_list) and r > 0 and r + c >= 2:`, cells will be indexed beginning with cell 1,1.

Comment: thanks very much.  I was trying to write a small scheduling program for my own work through pulp.  now i can move on to the next pulp stage.  what is the name of the area that I can read more on what you did there in tkinter?  thanks again.

Comment: There are **very** many resources. But it's about how *you* learn or prefer to learn. Some of the best succinct references (I like references as well as examples) is http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/. And you can always google for examples of what you're trying to implement.